# iPhone Simulator Refresh/Redraw View when debugging?

Tags: refresh, ios-simulator, redraw

anyone does knows how redraw a  view when debugging code?
When Xcode is in the debugger mode, doesn't refresh the screen. If I add a view or a button, nothing  is show on the screen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you need to rebuild the project so it deploys the latest app to the Simulator

Comment: This is not accurate.  When paused on a breakpoint you can redraw the view by running `e (void)[CATransaction flush]`

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for the swift equivalent:

```
(lldb) expr CATransaction.flush()
```

You can still use the objective-c version in a swift context so long as you manually set the expression language:

```
(lldb) expr -l objc -- (void)[CATransaction flush]
```

Answer (score 0):

When the application is paused you can update live in the simulator or on the device while you are still in the debugger using the LLDB command below:

```
 (lldb) e (void)[CATransaction flush]
```

if you have [Chisel](https://github.com/facebook/chisel) use the alias `caflush`